# Is there a way to save an ajax function/call so it can be reused?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm working on a web app using JavaScript and PHP and I'm finding myself re-coding the same ajax calls over and over again. Is there a way to save it as a function, with or without parameters, or even as a variable that can be used later?

Note: I'm still learning JavaScript as I go so I appreciate any tolerance for my ignorance.

For example, instead of this:

```
  $("body").on("click", ".all-forms-link", function() {
         $.ajax({ 
            url: "forms.php", 
            type: "post", 
            data: {formsPage: 1}, 
            success: function(data) {
                     stage.html(data)
             }

          }); 
     }); 
     //called several more times on different actions
```

Something like this:

```
      function loadForms() {
            $.ajax({ 
            url: "forms.php", 
            type: "post", 
            data: {formsPage: 1}, 
            success: function(data) {
                     stage.html(data)
                                     }
                   }); 
                             }

  body.on("click", ".all-forms-link", function() {
        loadForms(); //or something similar
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. When you create a named function declaration, for example:

```
function foo(){
   . . .
}
```

You may refer to that function by name anywhere a function is expected.

So, your code could be even simpler than what you showed with:

```js
function loadForms() {
  console.log("AJAX Call Initiated!");
  $.ajax({ 
    url: "forms.php", 
    type: "post", 
    data: {formsPage: 1}, 
    success: function(data) {
      stage.html(data)
    }
  }); 
}

// Just refer to your function's name (don't add parenthesis after 
// the name though because we don't want to execute it with this line
// we only want to refer to it) where a function is expected.
$(document).on("click", ".all-forms-link", loadForms);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all-forms-link">Click me</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Turns out, I had changed something in forms.php right before changing the function and the problem was with the php not the js, so my bad there. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ClayWhaley You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote and mark as the answer. Good luck!